# WinForm Chart - Increase Scroll Granularity

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

For an example of what I'm dealing with, create a WindowsForms App, create a fresh Chart, and add the following as a Load event:

```
this.chart1.Series.Clear();
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Interval = 1 / 24.0 / 60.0; // To increase selection granularity
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = ("M/d H:mm:ss");

var series = new Series("Some Series") {ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line};
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    series.Points.AddXY(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(i), i + 1);
}

this.chart1.Series.Add(series);
```

When I run this I'm able to zoom into the data to get a closer look, but the behavior of the horizontal scrollbar is not what I'm looking for; Clicking either arrow jumps an entire day in either direction, regardless of the Series' internal data. If there's less than a day's data, it will jump to the end. Dragging the bar is similarly restricted. How do I can specify what TimeSpan I want this interval to be, or to otherwise enable smooth scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is well hidden in documentation.

First we find [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456730.aspx), referring to to the `ScrollBar` property of the chart's `Axis` members. We're dealing with an `AxisScrollBar` object, and the information is in the "Remarks" section of this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axisscrollbar.aspx

> To control the large scrolling size, use the Size property of the ScaleView object. To set the small scrolling size, use the SmallScrollSize property of the AxisScaleView class.

Thus, for example,

```
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 50;
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = 5;
```

To have the scroll size correspond to time units in the view, use the `SmallScrollSizeType` property on the `AxisScaleView`object. Again an example, possible values for this property are documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datetimeintervaltype(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Weeks;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Did help expose another issue, where the scrollbar resizes itself as the user is scrolling. If anybody is curious, you have to set `chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Auto = false`, then do remember to unlock, redraw, and relock every time the graph is resized.